# How to set a value from observable to a variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a `UsernameService` that returns an observable which contains a json object. In `AnotherService`, I want to inject a value from the `UsernameService` object.

So far, I am able to subscribe to the observable from UsernameService and I can show it in the console.  I can even drill down and show one of the values from the object in the console.  However, I don't understand how to assign that value to a variable that I can then use.  Instead, when I try to assign the value to a variable, in the console I get: Subscriber `{closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null...etc`

Here's my example where I am successfully showing the observable value in the console:

```
import { UsernameService } from './username.service';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {

    username: any[] = [];

    constructor(private getUsernameService: UsernameService) { }

    someMethod() {
        let myFinalValue = this.getUsernameService.getUsername()
        .subscribe(username => console.log(username.data[0].AccountName));
    }
}
```

The code above results in the console correctly showing the value of the `AccountName` field which I am trying to  assign to the variable `myFinalValue`.  However, I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

When I try to use the same  technique to simply  get the value (instead of log in console), I get the generic: Subscriber `{closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null`...etc as I mentioned before.

Here's an example of the code that results in my error:

```
import { UsernameService } from './username.service';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {

    username: any[] = [];

    constructor(private getUsernameService: UsernameService) { }

    someMethod() {
        let myFinalValue = this.getUsernameService.getUsername()
        .subscribe(username => this.username = username.data[0].AccountName);
        console.log(myFinalValue);
    }
}
```

Ultimately, my goal is to just assign the value from *username.data[0].AccountName* to the variable *myFinalValue*.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that since the observable is asynchronous and as Suren said "callback will work only when it is finished, you don't know when", I needed to initiate the code that was subscribing to the first service in my component ngOnInIt. From there, I needed to pass the subscribe value to the method in the component that actually calls the subscribe form the service as a parameter.

Here's the piece form my component (you can see the this.username value passed to the getCharges() method as getCharges(accountName):

```
getCharges(accountName) {
  this.getChargesService.getCharges(accountName)
  .subscribe((charges) => {
      this.charges = charges.data;
      }, (error) => console.log(error) 
      )
  }


ngOnInit() {
this.getUsernameService.getUsername()
   .subscribe(username =>  { 
        this.username = username.data[0].AccountName;
        this.getCharges(this.username);
        })
   }
```

Then in the service file with the getUsernameService.getUsername() service/method, I was easily able to assign the parameter which contained my desired value to a variable.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

Because your call is an asynchronous (callback will work only when it is finished, you don't know when), you can't return a value from the asynchronous call, so you need only to assign it when the call is finished.
You need to do your logic which is related to the `username` you get in the `subscribe` method. You need to create a field to keep the value of the `username` for the later use in the class.

```
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {

    username: any[] = [];
    myFinalValue: string;

    constructor(private getUsernameService: UsernameService) { }

    someMethod() {
        this.getUsernameService.getUsername()
        .subscribe(username => this.myFinalValue = username.data[0].AccountName));
    }
}
```

Comment: OP might also try to use username.json() or username.text()

Comment: That solution is returning undefined.

Comment: Use myFinalValue only with binding, you can't know when it will be returned

Comment: Thanks for your input Suren, but I need the value from the observable to use in a service, not in a component/html template.  Is there a way to do binding inside a service as opposed to an html page?

Comment: You know it will be better to understand observables at all and then try to do something. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ See the basics and look at the methods. Maybe you can think out how to make your logic